# docker-compose can't use variables from .env

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, environment-variables

`Docker Compose` can't use variables from `.env` in `docker-compose.yml`. `.env` located in the same directory as `docker-compose.yml`.

.env:

```
port:3306
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
ports:
    - ${port}:${port}
```

The documentation shows exactly the same example and says that it works

```
web:
    image: "webapp:${TAG}"
```

I have error while executing `docker-compose up`

```
WARNING: The port variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.mariadb.ports is invalid: Invalid port ":", should be [[remote_ip:]remote_port[-remote_port]:]port[/protocol]
```

How to fix it?

Comment: `port:3306`? `port=3306`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/:

> Syntax rules
>
> These syntax rules apply to the .env file:
>
> - Compose expects each line in an env **file to be in VAR=VAL format.**
> - Lines beginning with # are processed as comments and ignored.
> - Blank lines are ignored.
> - There is no special handling of quotation marks. This means that they are part of the VAL.

in `.env`, use `=` instead of `:`

Answer (score 1):

It seems your .env format is wrong. Try:

```
PORT = 3306
```